# How to filter out columns in pd using the value of rows selected by a specific index row?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a df I have copied a small snippet of the output here including the desired result I basically want to filter by an index removing columns which do not conform to my search. I would like to basically only keep columns which 5 day change is >= 10%.

I tried `df = df.loc["5 Day Change" >= .1]` but it didnt work and I am not sure how to make it work.

```
               1    2   3   4
15/10/2020  23.53   15.06   396.700012  348.380005
16/10/2020  23.35   15.09   398.519989  348.399994
5 Day Change-0.049654 0.12  0.009   0.256
10 Day Change-0.014768 0.01 0.11    0.03
```

Return

```
                2   4
15/10/2020  15.06   348.380005
16/10/2020  15.09   348.399994
5 Day Change 0.12   0.256
10 Day Change 0.01  0.03
```

Comment: try `df = df.loc[(df.index == "5 Day Change") & (df[2] >= .1), [2,4]]` OR try this if your column names are strings and not integers:`df = df.loc[(df.index == "5 Day Change") & (df['2'] >= .1), ['2','4']]`

Comment: Is there no way to make this dynamic? I have thousands of columns

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Please see my answer.

Comment: _I tried df = df.loc["5 Day Change" >= .1] but it didnt work and I am not sure how to make it work._ Have you checked the docs for `.loc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `.T` to transpose the dataframe and then filter by row rather than column as it is easier to filter by rows in pandas. Then, transpose it back:

```
In[1]: 
                       1      2           3           4
15/10/2020     23.530000  15.06  396.700012  348.380005
16/10/2020     23.350000  15.09  398.519989  348.399994
5 Day Change   -0.049654   0.12    0.009000    0.256000
10 Day Change  -0.014768   0.01    0.110000    0.030000

df = df.T
df = df[df['5 Day Change'] >= .1].T
df
Out[1]: 
                   2           4
15/10/2020     15.06  348.380005
16/10/2020     15.09  348.399994
5 Day Change    0.12    0.256000
10 Day Change   0.01    0.030000
```